# Displaying a specific amount of strings out of an ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently trying to make a Mad Libs game, and all the words are stored in an ArrayList called `List`. Now, I want to display all the words within that list, but only 10 per line. Is there some formatting using `%f` or something that can solve this problem? I have looked far and wide on this site, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Just use a loop and add a linebreak after every 10th iteration.

Comment: Not sure if i fully understand your question, but have you tried using a foreach loop up to 10?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with foreach loops, but I will read up on them, thanks!

Comment: Look into `for` loops, `System.out.print()`, and `System.out.println()`.  This question is very basic loop iteration, and I do not think you've looked far and wide.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use a loop.  Iterate over the full list of words, and upon hitting every tenth word, print a newline separator.  Otherwise, print a space separator between each word.

```
List<String> words;
for (int i=0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    if (i % 10 > 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(words.get(i));
    if ((i+1) % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println("");     // print correct newline regardless of OS
    }
}
```

### Demo